# Attaching paragraph to the top of nested list highlights level change

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I'm working on a simple `office-js` Word app, built with the `Yeoman Generator`. I have a very basic document with the following structure:

```
1. This is heading one
   1.1 This is subheading 1
   1.2 This is subheading 2


Some random text here...

Paragraph I want to attach to the list from the beginning of my doc
```

When I try to attach this last paragraph to my list though, I'm getting the following output:

[Word document's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vAly.png):

[image]

It looks as though it's first trying to insert it to the `level=1` of that list (thus the initial `3`) and then actually inserts it to the root list's position (thus the secondary `2`).

The code I'm running looks as follows:

```
const insertHeading = async (event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) => {
  try {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
      const selection = context.document.getSelection();
      selection.load("paragraphs");
      await context.sync();

      const lists = context.document.body.lists;
      const list = lists.getFirst();
      const paragraph = selection.paragraphs.getFirst();
      list.load("id");
      await context.sync();

      paragraph.attachToList(list.id, 0);
      await context.sync();
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.info("Error occurred", error.debugInfo);
  } finally {
    event.completed();
  }
}
```

I'd expect this paragraph to be added as 2nd item of the root level (with `2.`) and without this turquoise strike, shown in the image above.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the expectation that Word would automatically choose to apply the level of the most recent list level is incorrect. Word is going to apply the level you specify in the second parameter of the attachToList method (i.e. 0 specifies "Level 1" and so on. If you want to apply the level most recently used you'll probably have to search backwards through the list paragraphs (somehow) to do that. The turquoise strike is a mystery - it looks just like a tracked deletion would look, but it isn't one. It disappears when you save. Maybe someone else can explain that one!

Comment: BTW, the turquoise strikethrough only seems to appear on the Online version of Word, not the Windows desktop version. Further, it *doesn't* appear if you either turn on Track changes before you run the code, or if you apply a level that *isn't* the last level before the selection (I think). I wondered if it might have something to do with the Editor add-in but could not find a way to change the behaviour.